# std::vector<T>::resize equivalent in swift

Tags: c++, swift

> `std::vector<T>::resize`
>
> Resizes the container so that it contains n elements.

The following code won't cause a `out of range` crash:

```
std::vector<int> vec; //0 items contained
vec.resize(10); // 10 items contained, using default constructor/initial value
cout << vec[5]; // prints 0
```

I don't find the equivalent of this method in swift Array

```
var arr = [Int]()
arr.reserveCapacity(10)
print(arr[0]) // crashes because there is nothing contained in this array, although its capacity is set to 10
```

`Array(repeating: T, count: Int)` doesn't satisfy my request because I need to `resize` an Array dynamically, i.e. the Array being resized may contain some data at the begining.

```
std::vector<int> vec; 
// something happend here and vec is now [1, 2, 3] 
// and I need a 6-element vector for subsequent processing. crop if vec is larger than 6 or fulfill with 0 if vec is smaller than 6
vec.resize(6) // this method exactly do what I wants
// For swift, I can't re-initiate an Array with the repeating constructor because it will overwrite the existing data
```

Is there a built-in method for swift Array to achieve this? or I can only write an extension for it?

Comment: Maybe a good starting point would be to read the documentation so that you know exactly how Swift arrays works...

Answer (score 0):

I scratched an extension (not tested)

```
extension Array {
    mutating func resize(_ size: Int, placeholder: Element) {
        var n = size
        if count < n {
            if capacity < n + count {
                reserveCapacity(n + count)
            }
            repeat {
                append(placeholder)
                n = n - 1
            } while n > 0
        } else if count > n {
            removeLast(count - n)
        }
    }
}
```